# import nltk is not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, scikit-learn, nltk

I am trying to import nltk but here is the error

```
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\chunked.py", line 21, in <module>

  from nltk.chunk import tagstr2tree      ImportError: cannot import name tagstr2tree
```

even I uninstalled Python27 and installed again. Actually I was working with nltk without any problem.

this error started to show up form the time I started to work with scikit

> from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
>
> from sklean.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB, GaussianNB, BernoulliNB

Does anybody knows how can I solve it ?

Comment: What is the name of your python code file?

Comment: It is classification.py

Comment: Did the change but not solved. even I uninstalled Python27 and installed again. Actually I was working with nltk without any problem. this error started to show up for no reason.

Comment: Please add the above information too to your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found what is the problem. In my project directory, I have saved one file with the name Pickle.py . I just changed the name of it and now problem solved.

Just be aware that sometimes module names and file names can conflict.